# Populating a list with lists (replicate, lapply)

Tags: r

How should I generate a list of lists of known size?

Currently I do it like that.

```
create_scout_bees <- function(search_space, num_scouts){
  gen_bee <- function(unused, sear_spac){
    create_random_bee(sear_spac)
  }
  bees <- lapply(1:num_scouts, gen_bee, search_space)
  #bees <- replicate(num_scouts, create_random_bee(search_space))
  cat('\nclass of bees is:',class(bees),'\n')
  bees
}
```

where `create_random_bee(sear_spac)` returns `return(list(vector=random_vector(search_space)))`. This seems to be too complicated. I found the `replicate` function (see comment in code). But it does not return the same thing. To be honest I'm not entirely sure what it returns.

The lapply option seems returns a list of lists

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$vector
[1] -3.772477 -4.178604


[[2]]
[[2]]$vector
[1] -1.237291 -2.430769


[[3]]
[[3]]$vector
[1] -2.211511 -1.352074


[[4]]
[[4]]$vector
[1]  4.102391 -1.437620


[[5]]
[[5]]$vector
[1] -0.1355444 -2.0270074
```

The replicate version returns a list

```
$vector
[1] 3.780779 3.588892

$vector
[1] -4.290371  4.098709

$vector
[1]  1.051525 -3.374406

$vector
[1] -0.4593861 -4.8412850

$vector
[1]  2.164383 -4.903347
```

I can index both returned values. But the second option seems to be just a list with 5 elements of type vector with the same key. When accessing by key it returns the first element.
How do you generate a list of lists of known size?

Comment: Thanks @akrun. If you add this as an answer then I accept it. Otherwhise I remove the question, after some time.

Comment: Okay, I will add that as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
replicate(5, list(vector=rnorm(2)), simplify=FALSE)
# [[1]]
#[[1]]$vector
#[1] -1.5239454 -0.1326934


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$vector
#[1] -1.4369404  0.3701259


#[[3]]
#[[3]]$vector
#[1]  0.3251298 -1.4289498


#[[4]]
#[[4]]$vector
#[1]  0.8346002 -0.2974959


#[[5]]
#[[5]]$vector
#[1]  0.4581858 -0.8066517
```